# Attempt to invoke interface method on a null object reference in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, nullpointerexception, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, mutablestateof

After implementing viewmodels to jetpack compose app when I running the app it's showing a error :-

**Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.Set.contains(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.Set.contains(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at com.example.android.ui.GameViewModel.pickRandomWordAndShuffle(GameViewModel.kt:21)
at com.example.android.ui.GameViewModel.(GameViewModel.kt:10)**

here is my code:-

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.example.android.unscramble.data.allWords
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asStateFlow


class GameViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState =
        MutableStateFlow(GameUiState(currentScrambledWord = pickRandomWordAndShuffle()))
    val uiState: StateFlow<GameUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    private var _count = 0
    val count: Int
        get() = _count

    private lateinit var currentWord: String
    private var usedWords: MutableSet<String> = mutableSetOf()

    private fun shuffleCurrentWord(word: String): String {
        val tempWord = word.toCharArray()
        // Scramble the word
        tempWord.shuffle()
        while (String(tempWord) == word) {
            tempWord.shuffle()
        }
        return String(tempWord)
    }

    private fun pickRandomWordAndShuffle(): String {
        // Continue picking up a new random word until you get one that hasn't been used before
        currentWord = allWords.random()
        if (usedWords.contains(currentWord)) {
            return pickRandomWordAndShuffle()
        } else {
            usedWords.add(currentWord)
            return shuffleCurrentWord(currentWord)
        }
    }

    private fun resetGame() {
        usedWords.clear()
        _uiState.value = GameUiState(currentScrambledWord = pickRandomWordAndShuffle())
    }
    init {
        resetGame()
    }
}
```

It's not showing any compile time errors. I don't konw what should I do.

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing `_uiState` before you initialize `usedWords`. This calls `pickRandomWordAndShuffle()` before `usedWords` has been initialized, so it's still `null` in the `GameViewModel` instance being created.

If you move the declaration of `usedWords` above `_uiState` it should work.

HOWEVER: It's generally a bad idea to call member functions before an instance has been fully initialized, for this exact reason.

You could make `_uiState` and `uiState` *lazy*, which would make this safer. For example:

```
// Copyright 2023 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

private val _uiState by lazy {
    MutableStateFlow(GameUiState(currentScrambledWord = pickRandomWordAndShuffle()))
}
val uiState: StateFlow<GameUiState> by lazy { _uiState.asStateFlow() }
```

which will wait until something uses `uiState` (which looking at your code only happens externally, so you'll be guaranteed that it won't be initialized until the `GameViewModel` has been fully initialized.